# Angular Material TextArea auto resize is not working with bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6

I have created a simple app and I have added angular material auto resize textarea(which is auto increased doesn't give scroll up to 5 lines). Here the problem is If I add bootstrap to my application, Angular material textarea losses it's functionality and some styles are overriding. How to make it work even If i Include bootstrap in my application?

Actual One :

https://stackblitz.com/angular/dkpvgbjaaey?file=app%2Ftext-field-autosize-textarea-example.ts

After Adding Bootstrap :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tqnzi-hx6cy8?file=index.html

Answer (score 3):

It's bit late... But i found a solution to this problem.
To fix auto resize you'd add this style to TextArea:

```
style="box-sizing:content-box;"
```